# javascript canvas drawing application selecting colors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Below is the code that allows the user to draw to the canvas. This works fine, the part which i have problem with is with selecting different colors with javascript so the user has more color choices

here is the code for the drawing part

```
window.addEventListener("load", canvasAnimate, false);

    function canvasAnimate() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', MouseIsMoving, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchit, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', dontDraw, false);
};

//  GLOBAL VARIABLES

    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    var MouseIsDown = false // this will be used to determine if the mouse is down or not


//   e means the event, this stores the mouse events in the variable mouseX and mouseY
    function MouseIsMoving(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft; //the offset makes the coordinates fit for     the canvas box
        mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        document.getElementById('mouseCoordinates').innerHTML = 'X: ' + mouseX + ' Y: ' +     mouseY;
        if (MouseIsDown) {
            context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function sketchit(e) {
        context.beginPath()
        context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        context.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY)
        context.lineCap = 'round'; //default lineCap and lineWidth
        context.lineWidth = 3;
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000' //default color
        context.stroke();
        MouseIsDown = true;
    };

    function dontDraw() {
        if (MouseIsDown) {
            MouseIsDown = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is what you want the user interface to select colors?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to select different colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="color" />` to create a colorpicker, the exact appearance will depend on the implementation of the browser.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQaxj/)

However, currently [only Google Chrome and Opera supports this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color). Other browsers will revert to a text field where the user can manually input a hex color.
If you want a cross-browser solution, you can use [this jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) or others found [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker).

Answer (score 0):

Two JavaScript color-picker apps:

The first covers all browsers back to IE6, and I think it is the best solution if you need to support old browsers:

https://github.com/DavidDurman/FlexiColorPicker

The second is for modern browsers that support the canvas tag.  I wrote it and call it MasterColorPicker.  It offers several different color-pickers in one package.  It already offers more than the standard Photoshop color-picker, and I'm working on the updated versions of all files and the overall project, and it will be all it can be...

http://softmoon-webware.com/MasterColorPicker_instructions.php